# IdentityServer4 access token after server reboot

Tags: identityserver4

I have implemented a Web API incorporating IdentityServer4 authentication as part of the web service.

If I reboot the server access tokens issued before the reboot are no longer valid.
I am persisting the IdentityServer data with AddConfigurationStore and AddOperationalStore.

Am I incorrect in thinking that the access tokens should been persisted ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An asymmetric key pair is used by IdentityServer4 to sign and validate JWTs. You should also persist this pair in addition to `AddOperationalStore` call. As described in [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/startup.html#refstartupkeymaterial):

> **AddSigningCredential**
>
> Adds a signing key service that provides the
>   specified key material to the various token creation/validation
>   services. You can pass in either an `X509Certificate2`, a
>   `SigningCredential` or a reference to a certificate from the certificate
>   store.
>
> **AddDeveloperSigningCredential**
>
> Same purpose as the temporary signing
>   credential. But this version persists the key to the file system so it
>   stays stable between server restarts. This addresses issues when the
>   client/api metadata caches get out of sync during development.

More info: [Cryptography, Keys and HTTPS](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/crypto.html#refcrypto).

`AddSigningCredential` example: [GitHub](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Samples/blob/327318e2d7cbd34057c84dbc549f08f3b4941873/NodeJsApi/src/QuickstartIdentityServer/Startup.cs#L20).

P.S. I guess `AddOperationalStore` stores refresh tokens only and it's by design.

Comment: Thanks, Pretty stupid of me - I had removed my certificate when moving between development machines.